# I can't prove $P[\tau_m<\infty]=1$ in this example

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stopping-times

I'm Trying to prove that given 
$$ X_t=\mu t+W_t $$

with  $W_t$ a Brownian Motion and 
$$\tau_m=\min  \{ t \geq 0 ; X_t = m\}$$

is the $m$ - first hitting time.

My goal is to prove that $\tau_m$ is finite almost surely : $P[\tau_m<\infty]=1$

My Attempt :

We know that the joint density of $W_t$ and $\tau = \min \{ t \geq 0 \ ; W_t = p \} $ is given by (using the reflection principle) :

$$ P[\tau < t , W_t \leq w ] = P[W_t \geq 2p-w]  $$

Writing $\tau_m$ as :

\begin{align*}\tau_m &= \min \{ t \geq 0 ; X_t = m \} \\
&= \min \{ t \geq 0 ; W_t = m - \mu t \}  \end{align*}

and putting $p=m - \mu t$ we get :

\begin{align*} P[\tau_m < t , X_t \leq x ] &= P[\tau_m < t , W_t \leq x - \mu t ] \\
&=  P[W_t \geq 2(m-\mu t) - x + \mu t]  \end{align*}

This gives :
 \begin{align*}
 P[\tau_m<t] &= 2 P[\tau_m < t , X_t \leq x ] \\
             &= 2 P[W_t \geq 2(m-\mu t) - x + \mu t] \\
             &= 2 \int _{2m - x - \mu t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t} } e^{-\frac{1}{2t}y^2} dy
\end{align*}

Now when I take the limit $t \rightarrow \infty$ this gives zero. Where did I go wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $x$?  After "This gives:", the LHS doesn't depend on $x$, but the RHS does?

Comment: If $m > 0$ and $\mu > 0$, then $X_{t} \geq W_{t}$ and $W$ hits $m$ in finite time almost surely.  Therefore, it only remains to consider the case when $m > 0$ and $\mu < 0$.  One can use the Girsanov transform to find the density of $\tau_{m}$.  Are you familiar with it?

Comment: The line $P[\tau_m<t] = 2 P[\tau_m < t , X_t \leq x ]$ is not correct. I've written this quickly thiking : $P[\tau_m<t] =  P[\tau_m < t , X_t \leq x ] + P[\tau_m < t , X_t \geq x ] $. How would you find the density of $\tau_m$ using Girsanov transform? Thank you